# Why does the C compiler generate integer multiplication with large, seemingly random, numbers?

Tags: assembly, c

Hi I want to write those instructions in C, I'm having trouble with `SAR EDX,6`,

**ASM**

```
MOV EDX,8
MOV EDI,1
IMUL EDI,EDX
MOV EAX,ED9CE24E
IMUL EDI
SAR EDX,6
```

**my try**

```
int edi=1
int edx=8
edi*=edx;
edx=((long long)edi*0xED9CE24E) >> 32 >> 6;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `sar` instruction is at least similar enough to `>>` to be valid in your code. Technically, `sar` is for `shift arithmetric right` which treats the carry/sign bit a bit different. But handling edge cases like overflow etc. can't be translated well from assembly to C anyway.

The question that's more interesting is "what does this do". In this case, the compiler is using a trick to replace an (expensive) float division by a (cheap) integer multiplication.

For example, calculating

```
int something=get_an_integer_from_somewhere();
int result=(int)((double)something/1.2345)
```

is quite expensive.

But, since `1/1.2345 = 0.810044552`, this is the same as

`result=(int)((double)something*0.810044552)`.

Well, we replaced a division by a multiplication, but this is still expensive.

However, we can write `0.810044552` as `3479114859`/`4294967296`. And `4294967296` "happens" to be 2^32. So we can rewrite the whole thing as

`result=something*3479114859/4294967296`. And suddenly we don't need the floating point multiplication/division anymore; we just need an integer division, which is, in this case, very inexpensive, as it's just a shift right by 32 bits.

And this is what your *original* C code seems to have been, which was then optimized by the compiler to not use a float division:

`result=input/8.619`

Try it with some example values.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details explanation, I'm trying to figure out how you calculated its division by `8.619` by following your instruction in reverse, `1/8.619=4983138759/4294967296` then what?

Comment: The code multiplies with `8`, then with `3986481742` which is `ED9CE24E` in decimal, so `8*3986481742=31891853936` altogether. Then it divides by `2^38` (`2^32` by using `edx` and ignoring `eax`, `2^6` due to the shift). `2^38` is `274877906944`. So the code multplies with `31891853936/274877906944`, or divides by `274877906944/31891853936`, which is `8.619`.